Can boundary condition be implemented as source term?
TL;DR: Can boundary condition be implemented as source term? Are they equivalent? This post is long because of its context and background.
I'm trying to simulate electrohydrodynamic flow over a domain.
The following is the governing equation to be solve using finite volume method software package, Ansys fluent:
$$
\nabla .E = \frac{\rho q}{\epsilon} = -\nabla^2\phi\text{ (Gauss's law)}
$$
$$
\nabla.U=0\text{ (Mass continuity)}
$$
$$
\frac{\partial(\rho U)}{\partial t}+U.\nabla(\rho U) = -\nabla P + \mu\nabla^2U + \rho qE\text{ (Modified Navier-Strokes)}
$$
$$
\frac{\partial(\rho q)}{\partial t}+\nabla.(\rho qU) = \text{source term} \text{ (charge conservation)}
$$
$$
\text{default_source_term} = D\nabla^2(q)-\nabla.(\rho qKE)
$$
In which, D is charge diffusion coefficient, and K and ion mobility. The remaining variables are as by convention of the equation name.
Side note:

Because the fluid is insulating, the electric field becomes irrotational, therefore magnetic effect is neglected.
The above governing equations is implemented in fluent by the use of 2 user defined scalars. Namely: voltage, $\phi$ in volts, and space charge, $q$ in Coulombs/kg of fluid.

Now, in my domain, there is a wall that is suppose to act like a sink that depletes a specified amount of charge flux through that wall.
In the software, I tried to set a boundary condition as flux and set it to specified amount. However, for some reason, the solution diverges.
However, with the exact same solver setting, but implementing the boundary condition as source term, the solution didn't diverge. Hence, I want to know: Is there a difference between setting the boundary condition on the wall versus boundary condition as source term?
To elaborate, the way I implement the flux boundary condition as source term is by having an if statement in the source term of the charge conservation equation and a 1d column of cell immediately adjacent to the wall acting as sink:
source = default_source_term;
IF cell is immediately adjacent to wall THEN {
    source = source - flux_amount;
}

Note that Ansys fluent will iterate/loop through the whole domain and call the above function for each cell in the domain.
My thinking is that the unit of the charge conservation equation is in coulombs/(m^3.s). Where as the flux is in unit of coulombs/(m^2.s). So I can just divide it by the "depth" of the wall. But, since my simulation is 2 dimensional, the "depth" is just 1m. Hence, the desired flux can just directly be added to the source term. Is this paragraph right? If I implement this, is the Gauss's law still conserved? Noting that there is E (electric field) in the default_source_term.
Side note:
If a Dirichlet boundary condition is to be implemented on the wall, instead of flux, i.e, fixed amount of charge at the wall. I think, then the code can just be modified into:
IF cell is immediately adjacent to wall THEN {
    source = K_p(desired_amount_of_charge - q);
}ELSE {
    source = default_source_term;
}

Where K_p is just some constant that can be modified to suit the stability of the solution. This is acting like a feedback control, for the charge at the wall to track a value of the desired_amount_of_charge. Is this correct?

What it sounds like you are doing is what is called a boundary penalty method in the literature. I believe it is nontrivial to incorporate such a penalty and keep everything else conserved. This is very much active research so it may be a more effective use of time to figure out whether your initial solution diverged because of an error in the mathematical problem or in translating it into your solver
